# How to mock DateTime.Now in unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

The normal solution is to hide it behind interface.

```
public class RecordService
{
    private readonly ISystemTime systemTime;

    public RecordService(ISystemTime systemTime)
    {
        this.systemTime = systemTime;
    }

    public void RouteRecord(Record record)
    {
        if (record.Created < 
            systemTime.CurrentTime().AddMonths(-2))
        {
            // process old record
        }

        // process the record
    }
}
```

In the unit test you can use mock object and decide what to return

```
[TestClass]
public class When_old_record_is_processed
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Then_it_is_moved_into_old_records_folder()
    {
        var systemTime = A.Fake<ISystemTime>();
        A.CallTo( () => system.Time.CurrentTime())
          .Returns(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1));

        var record = new Record(DateTime.Now);
        var service = new RecordService(systemTime);

        service.RouteRecord(record);

        // Asserts...
    }
}
```

I don’t like to inject another interface into my class just to get the current time. It feels too heavy solution for a such a small problem. The solution is to use static class with public function.

```
public static class SystemTime
{
    public static Func<DateTime> Now = () => DateTime.Now;
}
```

Now we can remove the ISystemTime injection and RecordService looks like this

```
public class RecordService
{
    public void RouteRecord(Record record)
    {
        if (record.Created < SystemTime.Now.AddMonths(-2))
        {
            // process old record
        }

    // process the record
    }
}
```

In the unit tests we can mock the system time just as easily.

```
[TestClass]
public class When_old_record_is_processed
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Then_it_is_moved_into_old_records_folder()
    { 
        SystemTime.Now = () => DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        var record = new Record(DateTime.Now);
        var service = new RecordService();

        service.RouteRecord(record);

        // Asserts...
    }
}
```

Of course there is a downside to all this. You are using public fields (The HORROR!) so nobody is stopping you writing code like this.

```
public class RecordService
{
    public void RouteRecord(Record record)
    { 
        SystemTime.Now = () => DateTime.Now.AddYears(10);
    } 
}
```

Also I think it is better to educate developers than create abstractions just to protect them from doing any mistakes. Other possible issues are related to running the tests. If you forget to restore the function back to it's original state it might affect other tests. This depends on the way unit test runner executes the tests.
You can use the same logic to mock file system operations

```
public static class FileSystem
{
    public static Action<string, string> MoveFile = File.Move;
}
```

In my opinion implementing this kind of functionality (mocking time, simple file system operations) using public functions is perfectly acceptable. It makes the code easier to read, decreases the dependencies and it is easy to mock in the unit tests.

Comment: Have you used moq? (or any other mocking framework) http://code.google.com/p/moq/

Comment: I fixed the formating of your code. Please compare it to your version to learn how to do it correctly.

Comment: @Magrangs: As all the other "normal" mocking frameworks, Moq can't mock static methods and properties like `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: I see no question - it's more like a blog-post

Comment: Ahhhhh.You would need a wrapper class or something then.

Comment: Great. Cool beans. What is the question?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to implement this by hand. You can use Moles framework to do this.
[channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Peli/Moles-Replace-any-NET-method-with-a-delegate)

Comment: And moq.. and many other mocking frameworks :-)

Comment: In fact this question amazed me as the first example of moles in the video is how easy to mock DateTime.Now :)

Comment: @Magrangs: Not correct. See my answer to your other comment above.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say getting the current time was such a small task, what if your application becomes international and is used in multiple timezones, which timezone are you getting the current time of, most likely you would want one common timezone to use, no matter your locale?

The interface allows you to abstract this knowledge away; I would consider retrieving the "current" time as a rather complicated task.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that we're talking about idiomatic c#, I don't quite understand the problems with the ceremony behind the interface. In essence, you have a `TimeProvider` that you you inject into the constructor as a dependency and you provide a stub for it to drive the logic of the relevant code under test.

I don't believe that your other approaches provide benefit and they have the negative aspect of not being idiomatic as well as eliminating the useful aspects of dependency injection (documenting dependencies, mocking, inversion of control, etc...)